# How do I remove gnome-panel settings?

Tags: 12.04, display, gnome-panel

My gnome-panel settings have gone crazy. 
I now have three bars at the top and three bars at the bottom, leaving limited space for working with.

Is there a way to remove all gnome-panels settings?

I just want to nuke everything and start over.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN3yL.jpg

Answer (score 2):

This should help--- to be able to access the GNOME panel settings or add applets, you need to hold the ALT key and right click the panel instead of simply right clicking it, as it used to be in GNOME 2.

Answer (score 1):

you can manually delete the folder `~/.gconf/apps/panel/`.

```
mkdir ~/gnomepanelbackup ; mv ~/.gconf/apps/panel ~/gnomepanelbackup
```

then

```
killall gnome-panel
```

after running these commands you will have backup of gnome-panel settings in `/gnomepanelbackup` in Home directory.

Comment: The directory ~/.gconf/apps/panel does not exist in my installation of 12.04. 'ls -al */* | grep panel' in the directory .gconf/apps returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

... and if [that](https://askubuntu.com/a/147723/22949) doesn't help: super(windows button)/Alt - right klick should enable you to delete the unwanted panels